# compare AtomicInteger without setting it

Tags: java

How can I compare an `AtomicInteger` with a given `int` value without setting the `AtomicInteger` to a new value? I don't see such a method in `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: What's wrong with `get()`?

Comment: @biziclop Well, this is what I am using now, but I thought that by the time `get()` returns, the value in the AtomicInteger may get updated to a new value... so I may get a stale value?

Comment: @peter.petrov That comparison might be synchronised ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ But that's the thing, I don't want to synchronize myself. If I do so, then OK, I know how to do it but I don't need an AtomicInteger anymore as I will be synchronizing it all myself.

Comment: I thought that the `get` of **Atomic**Integer would be also atomic ?? Am I wrong?

Comment: @Fildor I thought so too but then I looked at the source code. All it does is `return value`.

Comment: @peter.petrov Why stale value ? at that moment your comparison guaranteed to work.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ What if there're N other threads incrementing/decrementing it at the same time (while I am calling get(), and then a second step doing my comparison)? You see my concern? May I do my comparison wrong in that case? Maybe I am terribly misunderstanding something, I don't know (as this looks rather basic and there should be a safe way of doing it).

Comment: @peter.petrov That's inevitable. Imagine if there was some kind of atomic equals operation, and you did `if (foo.atomicEquals(42)) { bar(); }`, what would be the guarantee that the value of `foo` would still be `42` when you call `bar()`? Nothing. If you need such a guarantee, you need to synchronize the whole block. If you don't, just use `get()`.

Comment: @biziclop I got it now. Right, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> by the time get() returns, the value in the AtomicInteger may get updated to a new value... so I may get a stale value

By definition, if the value in the atomic integer gets updated right after you call `int i = atomic.get()` you will have a stale value in `i`. But that's just how concurrent programs work - when you consult a value, you know that it may already have changed.

What `AtomicInteger::get` guarantees is that when you call it, you will get the latest value available at the time of the call. A guarantee which you would not have with a plain `int` for example.

---

In other words, imagine the program below:

```
if (atomic.get() == 0) print("zero");
```

Even if you had some sort of `compareButNotSet` method, it would not help because by the time you reach the print statement the value of atomic may have changed anyway...

If you need to make sure that print is only called if the value is still 0, you need to synchronize (or use a lock around) the whole block.

Comment: Hm, does that mean I'd better synchronize it all myself? I want to do an atomic comparison which guarantees that the value will not change while I am comparing. That's all.

Comment: Hm, well, OK... I am a bit disappointed :) as I was somehow expecting something else ... but thanks.

Comment: @peter.petrov Why? You either do something after the comparison that still requires the value to be the same (->synchronize the whole block) or you don't, in which case "the value not changing while you're comparing" simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I guess I was somehow expecting that get and set are blocking methods, or say internally synchronized. Something like that. But even so, as your example says, it does not help. I was just a bit confused, I see now.

Answer (score 5):

You have [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#get--) method for it

> Gets the current value.

```
Returns:
the current value
```

You need not to worry about that synchronised part since  you compare that at particular point.

Comment: Well, I see what you mean but ... I think it's not so simple. Why are there these compare methods in AtomicInteger, if we're all supposed to just use get()?

Comment: Hm, well, OK... I am a bit disappointed :) as I was somehow expecting something else ... but thanks.